# Getting Forbidden/Permissions error on Apache setup for localhost

Tags: linux, localhost, fedora, apache

I'm asking this question on stackoverflow out of pure desperation. I have posted this on serverfault.com but I think the community is not big enough there to give me a working answer. Also this question [has been posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123533/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-index-html-on-this-server) but it seems that it faded away without a solution. So this is me revoking the question and trying again...

I have the exact same issue that the user [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554217/dmitry-makovetskiyd) had in the post linked to above. I'm running Fedora 18 64bit. I have apache installed through 'httpd'. I can hit the default apache page just fine when going to localhost with no html page in `/var/www/html/` but as soon as I paste a html document in there (named index.html) and hit localhost, I get an error stating:

```
Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

The file permissions on index.html is 755. If there's anything else please let me know! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is selinux turned on? btw, run *# ls -Z index.html*

Comment: @guido - Thanks for the reply, I'm quite new to linux.. What's selinux?

Comment: it's a general tool for enforcing system security through MAC that was introduced in f13 (i think) and turned on by default in f14 (idem); pls edit your question with the output of the command i told you above, and if you want to publish in /var/www/html or in public_html home directories.

Comment: in short, in this case, if the selinux attributes on the file ("context") do not match what apache user ("role") is, you get denied access. this is a colloquial explanation and hope other people do not jump at me for imprecision...

Comment: @DeanGrobler please print the output to these commands in your answer so we can better understand the problem: `ls -la /var/www` and `tail /etc/httpd/logs/error_log`. Did you install Apache with yum? Have you ever changed the settings in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`?